# Linux: Declare a shorthand for any command with fish

Tags: linux, fish

I'm using the fish shell and i would add custom shorthand for path i frequently use in my commands.

E.g: i would add something like `@` corresponding to my dev folder, very similar to how `~` works:

> `cd @`
> **=>** `cd /home/sigma/dev`

> `some_command @/foo @/bar` **=>** `some_command /home/sigma/dev/foo /home/sigma/dev/bar`

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable:

```
set -g dev /home/sigma/dev
cd $dev
some_command $dev/foo $dev/bar
```

Comment: This looks like a fair trade off, but out of curiosity i wonder if there would be a way to set behavior to special chars

Comment: No. Variable names can only include specific characters ([letters, digits and underscores](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#shell-variable-and-function-names)), and things like `@` and `/` aren't included. This won't be changed because it's important to determine where the variable name ends - e.g. `ssh $user@$host`. If `@` was allowed that would try to read the variable `user@`.

Comment: In general fish tries to do less with special characters, as a reaction to the many uses of weird sigils in posix shell script. The trade-off is that this makes it worse at code golf.

Answer (score 0):

I'd normally advice writing a wrapper function around the cd *command*, but fish already provides cd as a wrapper function.

I do something like this:

```sh
function cddev
  cd /home/sigma/dev
end
```

Save that as `~/.config/fish/functions/cddev.fish`